# How can I set 'this' to point to an object for methods on attributes?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm creating a rather large prototype for an object, and am trying to collect functions into attributes to organize them based on what they do. This gives me code that looks like this:

```
function MyConstructor(name){

    this.name = name || 'billy!';

}

MyConstructor.prototype.stringFns = {};

MyConstructor.prototype.stringFns.helloWorld = function(){
    alert('hello world!');
}

MyConstructor.prototype.stringFns.helloMe = function(){
    alert('hello ' + this.name); // <- THIS DOESN'T WORK
}
```

It all goes great until the last line. Well, not the last line. The close brace works fine. In the second last line, though, `this` does not point to the object that I've constructed. It points to the `stringFns` attribute on that object.

Is there a good way to change what `this` will point to for all methods on the `stringFns` object?

Comment: "I'm creating a rather large prototype for an object". Advice: Don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `call()`, `bind()` or `apply()` to set the value of `this`

```
var test = new MyConstructor('Dave');

test.stringFns.helloMe.call(test);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GLYS4/)

Comment: I'd like to define this where I create the methods, rather than where I call them. Is that possible?

Comment: @ckersch - nope, not like that, you've just created a new empty object in stringFns, and then you're adding properties to that objects, and the scope of the constructor is lost in those properties.